# How To Create Different Submit Actions in Rails 3 with respond_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to be able to do the following actions with a form submit using respond_with:

1. Submit then redirect to index
2. Submit then stay in the form
3. Submit and show the created record

the default action for respond_with is to redirect to the show action. How can I make the controller respond depending on the type of button clicked?

these "submits" will occur during create and update actions. For example, how would the create action in this code respond to whichever among the three submit buttons is clicked(Submit and Edit, Submit and Show, Submit and Show INdex)

```
def new
    respond_with(@business=Business.new)
  end

  def create
    @business = Business.new(params[:business])
    flash[:notice] = t("flash.actions.create.notice", {:resource_name => "Business"}) if @business.save
    respond_with(@business)
  end
```

Comment: If they are all submit buttons then what are we going to switch on? Can you provide any relevant code? Also, when would each to the three actions take place?

Comment: I have made the necessary edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view, using the values `submit_and_edit`, `submit_and_show` and `submit_and_show_index`, you would do this in your controller:

```
def create
  @business = Business.new(params[:business])
  flash[:notice] = t("flash.actions.create.notice", {:resource_name => "Business"}) if      @business.save
  location = case params[:submit]
  when 'submit_and_edit'
    edit_business_url
  when 'submit_and_show'
    business_url
  when 'submit_and_show_index'
    redirect_to businesses_url
  end
  respond_with(@business, :location => location)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is good practice to just have one submit button so that the user has an expectation of what happens next (usually to go to the show page).

If you want 3 submit buttons, then you can use Javascript to set a field on the data before submission. In the HTML (assuming ERB) add a hidden field and ids to the buttons:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :action, "", id='next_action' %>

<%= f.submit "Submit and Show, id='show' %>
<%= f.submit "Submit and Edit id='edit'%>
<%= f.submit "Submit and Index id='index'%>
```

Now you need to add click handlers, so in the .js.coffee:

```
$(":submit").click ->
    $('#next_action').val = $(this).attr('id')
    $(this).closest(':form').submit()
```

That should find the hidden field with an id of next_action', set its value to the id of the button clicked, then submit the form.

Now in your controller you will have access to `params[:next_action]` and you can redirect to the subsequent page from there.